# Matplotlib zoom entire figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to work out how to zoom an entire figure, not just the subplots within the figure. The following code is a slightly modified matplotlib example and shows that subplot axis limits can be adjusted manually. Likewise the box zoom only allows zooming in on a subplot (or linked subplots). How to zoom the entire figure?

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy
figsrc = figure()

axsrc = figsrc.add_subplot(121, xlim=(0,1), ylim=(0,1), autoscale_on=False)
axzoom = figsrc.add_subplot(122, xlim=(0.45,0.55), ylim=(0.4,.6),
                                                autoscale_on=False)
axsrc.set_title('Click to zoom')
axzoom.set_title('zoom window')
x,y,s,c = numpy.random.rand(4,200)
s *= 200

axsrc.scatter(x,y,s,c)
axzoom.scatter(x,y,s,c)

def onpress(event):
    if event.button!=1: return
    x,y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    axzoom.set_xlim(x-0.1, x+0.1)
    axzoom.set_ylim(y-0.1, y+0.1)
    figsrc.canvas.draw()

figsrc.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onpress)
show()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'zoom the entire figure'?  Just make the window bigger?

Comment: Sort of, say window size is 400x400 and figure size is 300x300 with subplots sized 100x200. Keep window at 400x400, change figure size to 500x500 (ie cut off if doesn't fit in window) and scale subplot size accordingly. Now I think I see how to do this - just set figure size as required ;-)

Comment: By design the top-most layer of artist positioning is done in 'figure fraction' and most of the default GUI embeddings pin the figure size to match the window size.  If you have sorted this out please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using the canvas.resize resize method.

Note that the home button will not restore the original view. I haven't been able to track the toolbar.home() method further than a reference to QtCore.Qt.Key_Home: 'home' in backend_qt5.py:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy
figsrc = figure()

axsrc = figsrc.add_subplot(121, xlim=(0,1), ylim=(0,1), autoscale_on=False)
axzoom = figsrc.add_subplot(122, xlim=(0.45,0.55), ylim=(0.4,.6),
                                                autoscale_on=False)
axsrc.set_title('LMB to zoom in, RMB to zoom out')
axzoom.set_title('zoom window')
x,y,s,c = numpy.random.rand(4,200)
s *= 200

axsrc.scatter(x,y,s,c)
axzoom.scatter(x,y,s,c)

def onpress(event):
    if event.button==1: 
        zoomIn()
    elif event.button==3:
        zoomOut()

def zoomIn():
    aw, ah = figsrc.canvas.get_width_height()
    aw *= 1.2
    ah *= 1.2
    figsrc.canvas.resize(aw, ah)
    figsrc.canvas.draw()

def zoomOut():
    aw, ah = figsrc.canvas.get_width_height()
    if (aw !=0) and (ah != 0):
        aw /= 1.2
        ah /= 1.2
        figsrc.canvas.resize(aw, ah)
        figsrc.canvas.draw()


figsrc.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onpress)
show()
```